# Vue 3 Parsing and Building URL query nested object using Vue router

Tags: vuejs3

I want to create a URL with object in the query params part. Something like below

```
https://www.example.com/?pagination[page]=1&pagination[pageSize]=10
```

How to parse this kind of query into an object below

```
pagination = {
   page: 1,
   pageSize: 10
}
```

Similarly, how given an object like above, how to create the route object so I can assign it to `<router-link>` component.

So I am currently want to build a pagination, something like below.

```
<li v-for="page in [...Array(10).keys()]">
   <router-link :to="generatePageRoute(page)">
      {{ page }}
   </router-link>
</li>
```

```
export default class Pagination extends Vue {
    generatePageRoute(page: number): RouteLocationRaw {
       // what goes here?
    }

}
```

What should I put in the function so the `router-link` will produce something like below

```
<a href="https://www.example.com?pagination[page]=1">
```

Comment: It is a straightforward task. You can pass any dynamic string to `router-link`. Your task is just to build your link from the number. Something like this: `https://www.example.com?pagination[page]=${page}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Composition API and Vue-Router:

```html
<script setup>
const route = useRoute()
console.log(route.query)
</script>
```

`.query` value contains query params as an object.

In a link in question, there is just one root/index component where you should read query params to use them and query database or what ever. There was never in any human known framework a convention to use query params in a router to display different route, so you won't need `<router-link>` for params. Query params are used to display correct data in a component, not correct route?